# Dell Vostro 3460 - can i use ubuntu?

Tags: dell

Does anyone know Dell Laptops well - most use same hardware.. I can use Latitube 3460 according to the database... Can I use Ubuntu on Dell Vostro 3460?

Answer (score 1):

Dell actually ships newer [dell xps](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/xps-13-developer-edition/spd/xps-13-9360-laptop/cax13w10h7b5128ubuntu) laptops WITH ubuntu pre installed on them. I'm assuming they probably don't change their hardware drivers too drastically, so older ones should be able to handle ubuntu. Just try to go with an LTS version, like [ubuntu 16.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Their hardware should work just fine, but with linux you'll probably run into little issues here and there, theres usually a host of issues in forums (like this one!) that have been answered, so you'll have plenty of support for that

Comment: I have an old Latitude D520 and it works fine with Kubuntu 14.04 -- even the bluetooth.  Dell's hardware is well supported.